# Should I store both birthday and age?

Tags: sql, database

Im making an app that uses both birthday and age to make some deductions, 
but as the age can be obtain through the birthday and current date, Im questioning if I should be storing them both and not just the date, for one part I could use the age attribute to simplify some querys without converting dates, what would be the right thing to do following conventions?

Comment: Full normalisation would say you have to get rid of age, but denormalisation like this is generally considered OK when it can speed up other operations.

Comment: @Nick why u not post it as an answer but comment?

Comment: If you want to simplify queries you could write a function to calculate age rather than recoding in every query.

Comment: @no0ob because I didn't want to go into the detail required of a good answer.

Comment: @P.Salmon that still requires compute time. Less effort to do it once on insert.

Comment: @Nick https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments/

Comment: @no0ob I think someone with far more experience than me will post a good answer to this question.

Comment: @nick performance wasn't mentioned in the question simplification was,

Comment: @P.Salmon agreed but it is one of the important considerations when deciding to denormalise data.

Comment: As a general rule, never store derived/derivable data

Comment: @Nick, yeah, I think that's what I need it to know.. thank you!

Comment: I think I will just store the birthday, to be more in line with the conventions

Comment: @MichalTurczyn makes very valid points in his answer. It is always safer to recalculate.

Comment: @no0ob, I will still mark the right answer if someone say it in the answers section

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: DRY principle => Do not repeat yourself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calculations based on data should be always... calculated, not stored. Well, not always, usually, but
it depends on situation. Below are couple of pros and cons:

**Cons**

- calculation logic might change, so stored values will be no loner valid.
- or invalid data could be entered (and you will receive invalid data when querying).
- or the result changes with time, as age does, eg. today you have 20 years, but in one year you will have 21.

**Pros**

- however, as @RonenAriely mentioned, storing calculated data in order to gain performance is one of pros of such approach.

So, to sum up, you should make calculations, like `DATEDIFF(NOW(), DateOfBirth)` to get an age, as the result changes in time and the function don't influence performance much.

Comment: This statement`Calculations based on data should be **always**... calculated, not stored` as a general statement is wrong. There are lot of cases that it is good idea to store data after ETL in order to get better performance in future uses of the value. This procedure is very common for example in Data Warehouse or reporting databases especially when the Calculation is complex and can lower performance. In other cases we can use indexed computed column and PERSISTED to specify that the Database Engine will physically store the computed values! I am not talking about this case but in general.

Comment: @RonenAriely Good remarks, storing data in order to gain performance is definietely good approach. Everything has its pros and cons :) I will include this in my answer.

Comment: The reason that I am not talking about this specific case but in general, is that we did not got any information that can help answer the question for specific case as we have no description of specific case. Therefore it is not professional to advice the user what to do, in my opinion. We can only give golden rules and explain that the answer is "depend" and explain what can be the parameters for each answer.

Comment: "`I will include this in my answer`" this is a good idea @MichałTurczyn :-)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I think that You must remove the word "always" or at least replace it with "usually" if you don't want to remove it. Personally, I prefer to remove it, and to change the approach from specific answer to "advantages and disadvantages" of each option, since both options can be the right answer for different systems :-) . In this case where we only need the age is is probably better not t store the age since the calculation is pretty fast and simple

Comment: I cannot fix typo since time out, but last sentence should be: `In this case where we only need the age, then it is probably much better NOT to store the age, since the calculation is pretty fast and simple` (by the way, notice that I do not give advice for specific case, which I am not fully familiar with the system. Instead I use "probably")

Answer (score 3):

I would say store just the DOB and calculate the age when using.

I mainly prefer this because age will continuously change and you have to make sure to update it depending on how accurately you are measuring it. This will kind of beat the purpose of computing once and using multiple times because you'll be recomputing a lot of times. Then since it is redundant it'll also unnecessarily occupy space in your tables.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 2):

Generally only birth date is stored. 
You can create a common helper method to calculate age. Preferably static to avoid additional memory consumption.

Also saving age in database makes less sense as in such a case you would be required to run a daily cron to see which user's age is increasing by 1 that day and then update in the database.

Answer (score 2):

As said [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/295),

> you have to ensure that it is not possible for the derived value to
>   become out-of-date undetected.

Birthday never goes `out-of-date` so you would be OK!

Answer (score 1):

Better to follow the normalised approach and only store date of birth. Age would be marginally quicker to retrieve but, for that to be correct, you'd have to refresh the table on a daily basis.

If you were running a DB search on age range, then you could convert min and max ages to an upper and lower date of birth based on the current date and then search accordingly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30643554)

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes: It's a simple answer to a simple question, unless you lost something in translation. Your patronizing comments are both unhelpful and unnecessary. Those of a more sensitive disposition than myself might be discouraged from further posting on receiving something like that.

Comment: You should not feel discouraged from posting, rather, feel encouraged to see how you can improve your answers - check [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and any other resources available in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). The comments I made are done automatically by the system during the review queue. There is nothing personal.

Comment: how come "it does not provide an answer to the question" ? It does, and also provides the cons of not following the suggested approach. @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes you're the one with the comment that does not add much in here